# Create DataFrame from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I request data from a table in a database and each line comes as a dictionary like this one :

```
{
    "timestamp" : 1234657890,
    "prices" : {
                   "AAA" : 111,
                   "BBB" : 222,
                    ...
                   "ZZZ" : 999
               }
}
```

From all those lines i wanted to create a dataframe like this:

```
Timestamp    AAA    BBB    ...   ZZZ
1234657890   111    222    ...   999
1234567891   110    223    ...   997
   ...
1324657899   123    208    ...  1024
```

So i did :

```
rawData = database_request()
listPrices = []
for row in rawData
    tmp = {'timestamp': row['timestamp']}
    tmp.update({name : price for name,price in row['prices'].items()})
    listPrices.append(tmp)
df = pd.DataFrame(listePrices)
```

So i was wondering if there were a more pythonic way to do this ?

Comment: Does it only have `prices` and `timestamps` in the dictionary?

Comment: yes only those two fields

Comment: You need [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html#pandas-json-normalize) here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `rawData` (which should be ideally named `raw_data`, python suggests a style guide to name variables and functions in `lower_snake_case`) is already in a list structure. You can manipulate this in place, without having to process the whole dataset manually.

```
for row in raw_data:
    row.update(row.pop("prices"))
```